# Extensionless alias for a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, aspdotnetstorefront

I am using ML 5.0 version of ASPDotNetStoreFront and am facing issues with an extension-less URL rewrite.

I have the following situation.
I need to create an alias - /dummykit for a valid product page url /productdetails.aspx

I have a dev box where I have made an entry to the rewrite rules for the above scenario and when I run the application from my Visual Studio, the alias works perfectly i.e.

http:///dummykit redirects to http:///productdetails.aspx

But when I deploy the same changes onto the staging environment, the alias does not work and shows the IIS 404 error page.
Instead, if I update the alias to /dummykit.aspx, the things work fine.

I tried the following things -

1. Wildcard Mapping in IIS
2. urlMapping

The environment is IIS 6 / Asp.Net 2.0 on Windows Server 2003 SP2

Please help me through this.

Answer (score 0):

That is an old version of ASPDNSF

have you checked your domain settings? You will have three settings one for development, staging and production. Make sure the urls are as they should be. Also check the app configs that relate to the domains. I am not familiar with versions beyond 7 but this is usually the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed the below approaches and found that all of them had one major drawback i.e. they allowed ALL requests to reach my managed code -

1. Wild card mapping
2. runManagedCodeForAllRequests = true  attribute for modules node in web.config

As an alternate, we tried a work around, we simply created a folder in IIS with the same name as that of the required alias and set the folder's Redirect to URL property to the required redirect URL and BINGO !!!!

Yes this is not a clean approach but for a legacy code which was not supposed to be changed a lot, the trick worked well.